# cant compile apk using Game Maker Studio

Tags: android, build, compilation

I just updated the build tools using android SDK manager.

Now I cant compile apk using game maker studio.

Here is the error output from the console.

I dont think i have changed anything except windows update.  I have windows 10, 64 bit

```
Stats : GMA : Elapsed=6821.0873
Stats : GMA : sp=32,au=0,bk=3,pt=0,sc=11,sh=0,fo=4,tl=0,ob=41,ro=3,da=0,ex=1,ma=29,fm=0x49E50A39
cmd /c ""C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Android\runner\gradle\gradlew"" build -x assembleDebug

:com.mysite.myapp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.mysite.myapp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.mysite.myapp:checkReleaseManifest
:com.mysite.myapp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.mysite.myapp:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:com.mysite.myapp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
:com.mysite.myapp:prepareReleaseDependencies
:com.mysite.myapp:compileReleaseAidl
:com.mysite.myapp:compileReleaseRenderscript
:com.mysite.myapp:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:com.mysite.myapp:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.mysite.myapp:mergeReleaseAssets
:com.mysite.myapp:generateReleaseResValues
:com.mysite.myapp:generateReleaseResources
:com.mysite.myapp:mergeReleaseResources
:com.mysite.myapp:processArmeabi-v7aReleaseManifest
Warning: C:\Users\pc\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\MobiPC_App\Android\Default\com.mysite.myapp\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:3-182:17 Warning:
    application@android:label was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:28 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
Warning: C:\Users\pc\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\MobiPC_App\Android\Default\com.mysite.myapp\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:5-35:16 Warning:
    activity#com.mysite.myapp.RunnerActivity@android:label was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\pc\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\MobiPC_App\Android\Default\com.mysite.myapp\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:3-182:17 Warning:
    application@android:label was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:28 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\pc\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\MobiPC_App\Android\Default\com.mysite.myapp\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:29:5-35:16 Warning:
    activity#com.mysite.myapp.RunnerActivity@android:label was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:29 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
:com.mysite.myapp:processArmeabi-v7aReleaseResourcesC:\Users\pc\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\MobiPC_App\Android\Default\com.mysite.myapp\build\intermediates\manifests\full\armeabi-v7a\release\AndroidManifest.xml:78:28-65 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.mysite.myapp:processArmeabi-v7aReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.612 secs
Create finished: 01:33:39
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the buils tools version to the latest version.
In preferences I set the cache path to a shorter one

I also uninstalled an extension called "APPODEAL", i think this was causing problems too.

Now I managed to get apk compiled