# GameMaker: Studio Android fail to build ProcessException

Tags: android, apk, game-maker

I've been trying for the last several days to build and run the GameMaker: Studio Android Google Mobile Ads app demo on my Samsung Galaxy S6. I finally have all the correct things installed I believe, and I've managed to solve a few other build errors before this, but I've hit a brick wall and despite all my searching I have not found an answer. My problem is very similar to [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671425/cant-compile-apk-using-game-maker-studio) which poster said he solved by setting the build tools to the latest version. I don't know what he means by that.

The full compile form is too long to fit in a StackOverflow question, but I believe the only really relevant bit is the exception line:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\gunna_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I've been pulling my hair out with this and any help would be immensely appreciated.

I followed the [GameMaker: Studio Android instructions](http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216753498-GameMaker-Studio-Android-SDK-and-NDK-setup-) perfectly, with the only hiccup being the local IP address, which is supposed to be in the format **xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24** such as **192.168.1.0/24**. My IPv4 adress is **10.0.1.129**. Not knowing what to do, I entered **10.0.1.0/24** into the Web Server IP allowed list, ignoring the last number. However I do not believe that really has anything to do with this problem, as I'm trying to run the GM:S app on my Android device over USB cable.

I believe I have all the right modules installed in the Android SDK Manager:
[image: Android SDK Manager installs 1][image: Android SDK Manager installs 2]

And my JDK, SDK, NDK, and Keystore are all accepted it seems:
[image: GameMaker: Studio Android Preferences SDK, NDK, JDK, Keystore found]

I've been able to run and install Android apps made in Android Studio from this computer to this Android device (Android version 6.0.1), but GameMaker: Studio is just not having it. (And just to verify, I have bought GameMaker: Studio Professional and Android)

I don't have any weird extensions or plugins. I'm simply trying to run a GameMaker: Studio application on my Android device. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven't solved this:

1. Make sure your PC doesn't have a pending Windows update (if you use Windows).
2. Make sure your phone is in the right mode to accept files and install from GameMaker.
3. Try to run a very simple project with only an empty room.
4. Make sure to have all packages up-to-date.
5. Potentially reinstall the hole Android SDK lib.
6. Make sure that your device is connected and is found by the ADB.
7. If GameMaker tries to start the network connection between your PC and the Android device, it means that it failed doing so over the cable.